# Getting input date from the user in python using datetime.datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-2.7

I am trying to get input date from the user and store it in the form of

```
dt_start = dt.datetime(2006, 1, 1)
```

I am currently doing this:

```
i = str(raw_input('date'))
dt_start = dt.datetime(i)
```

But it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/.../sim.py", line 18, in <module>
    dt_start = dt.datetime(i)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Are you expecting the user to enter "2006, 1, 1" as a string?

Comment: After using the solution form @A.Rodas, I get this error:

Comment: in <module>
    dt_start = dt.strptime(i, '%Y, %m, %d')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: Based on your example you need to use dt.datetime.strptime.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the `%Y, %m, %d` format, you can try with [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime

i = str(raw_input('date'))
try:
    dt_start = datetime.strptime(i, '%Y, %m, %d')
except ValueError:
    print "Incorrect format"
```

Answer (score 3):

datetime() only takes int as parameter.

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_entry = input('Enter a date (i.e. 2017,7,1)')
year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split(','))
date = datetime(year, month, day)
```