# How do I check if x has more or less than seven integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = []
y = int(input("Hello, please enter your date of birth in this format: DDMMYYYY"))
x.append(y)
b = len.x()
if b > 7:
    input("Please enter your date of birth correctly in the above format")
elif b < 7:
    input("Please enter your date of birth correctly in the above format")
```

At the moment I'm getting this error:

> b = len.x()
>
> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no
> attribute 'x'

Sorry, I'm quite new to python, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Why did you try `len.x()`?! Have you considered reading Python's documentation, rather than just randomly guessing?

Comment: Kind of weird but: len(str(y))

Comment: Don't edit your question to the correct syntax. Leave as it was, and, if you want, answer your own question. Don't modify the original question to have the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout the solution given in the below thread if you are dealing with date and time.

[Getting input date from the user in python using datetime.datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581629/getting-input-date-from-the-user-in-python-using-datetime-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Python'a `len()` is a **function**. It does not work like you think it does. What you doing is incorrect. Instead of this:

`b = len.x()`

Do this:

`b = len(str(x))`

You seem to be confused about the `len()` function. I suggest you read the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) about it.